# Block read data for period of time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I wrote web application in asp.net webforms, where I have pool of tasks for users, and I have some dilemma. 
When user choose some task, another user shouldn't be able to choose same task.

My actual idea is to add column with date "Period" into table (sql server) with tasks, which is renewed when user working on it, and column "busy". In the backround would work some thread which renews this date every for ex. 5 min and one time set "busy" to 1.(it starts when user open site with task)

In the database I would have job which would starts every ex. 7 min, and set column "busy" for 0 if datetime in "period" is older then 5 min, then tasks is coming back to pool.

So when user finished working on task, job push it back to pool afte rsome time. Of course user can click some button and set busy o into 0. I want to achieve that task is not available while someone works on it. I do not know if it is good aprroach. Mayby somene has any experience with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not a good approach.

The task you are doing is basically a work around to implement the functionality, if you are delivering this to client its a big NO.

I would suggest you to use Locking of table.
Check this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026(v=sql.80).aspx

Also if you are playing around with database in code , it's highly recommended to use transactions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach at all.

First, you are creating a too complicated solution for something simple.

You start with defining the states of your Task... for example:

- Pending
- Busy (when a user opens and starts working on it)
- Finished

When a user opens a task you only need to Update the task directly to Busy. Database will endure only one client changes the state of the table when you call the Update statement.

Then you get the row count, if it is 1, then you have now ownership of the task only in this case you return the task information, otherwise, just raise an error.

You need to handle this error in ASP.NET.

For example:

```
UPDATE MY_TASKS SET STATUS = 'Busy' WHEN TASK_ID = 'some-id' AND TASK_STATUS <> 'Busy'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MY_TASKS WHERE TASK_ID = 'some-id'

END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Another user is working on this task', 16, 1) 
END
```

You can decorate this code as you wish, put a maximum period, create more states, control the transition between states, like in a finite state machine... but please dont try to kill a fly with an atom bomb.

Comment: This is approach, that i am using. Backround thread in my opinion is needed. There would be of course button to release task, but if someone lose connection or close browser, task would be still busy. Job on sql would check if this situation happened (last access time is ex. very old), if yes he would release this task. Mayby I am wrong, and missing something.